# Is there a way to make Mockito doNothing() when a method call actually returns something

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So I have this method that internally calls another service and for my testing purpose I dont care about this internal call and I dont want this internal service to do anything.

For e.g.

```
public void testMyMethod() {
        List<String> strings = otherService.getList(Employee);
}
```

Now I would like to use mockito in a way that this otherService.getList(Employee) does not do anything. It simply skips the execution for this one.

Comment: I believe you can create a mock for otherService and then do something like ```when(otherService.getList(someargs)).doNothing()```. Don't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: If `otherService` is a reference to a mock, that's already the default behavior (and returns `null`).

Comment: Correction: The default behaviour of Mockito is to return an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already inject mock otherService, all the method calls in `otherService.getList(Employee.class)` will return an empty `List` as default unless you explicitly tell Mockito to return something (by using `thenReturn`) only if they are not void method. It depends on the business process in the `getList` method about what will it return.

TLDR, explicitly tell Mockito what to do for all method calls in the `getList` method so that the return value will meet your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` and `thenReturn` as a normal test.

For instance, you can have this code:

```
public class Test 
{
    private OtherService otherService;

    public void doSomething() {
        otherService.getList(new Employee("X"));
    }

    /* Getters/Setters/Contructors */
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest
{
    @Mock
    private OtherService otherService;

    @InjectMocks
    private Test test; // Test uses 'otherService' internally

    @Test
    public void testVoid()
    {
        test.doSomething(); // 'test' do something and it also invokes your otherService 

        // Mock your otherService method to return null (or whatever you want)
        when(otherService.getList(any(Employee.class))).thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: this only changes the return value. But the method still executes.

Comment: @mudit_sen not really, mockito creates a proxy class and if the signature matches with the mocking configuration then the real method is not called but the mockito proxy class. You might be confusing with the other annotation `@Spy` that uses the real object instead.